# MUI - Data grid - Aggregation - can we show aggregation result (sum) in the table header?

Tags: material-ui, aggregation, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm a designer and I'm desiging a dashboard that will be coded using MUI library for React. I have a question regarding Data aggregation. I found these resources in the official documentation:https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/aggregation/

My question is - could we display the aggreagtion of a column (its sum) right after its name in the table header.

So instead of this (which is deafult):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM9fo.jpg)

Could we make it look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjFay.jpg)

Thanks a lot!

I used Google to try and find an answer but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codesandbox with something that might work, found in their github issues:

Codesandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fermat-0qmes4?file=/demo.tsx

Issue: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/7129#issuecomment-1342917200